# How to share records for Territory group

Tags: sharing, record, territory-management

I am trying to share record (Account) to Territory. I followed steps explained in [Granting Access to Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/granting_access_to_records.htm). I have activated Enterprise Territory Management and created few territories. Still, I don't find any type option to choose Territory Or Territories and Subordinates in Search Type drop down of New Sharing screen. My current options are :- Manage Groups (and Subordinates), Partner Users, Portal Roles (and Subordinates), Public Groups, Roles (and Subordinates) & Users

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I think you should Assignee Territories to your account first, Then you can find this territory in you User and Group Sharing. Hope it can help you.

Comment: I could add accounts to territory under territory model -> hierarchy -> choose one territory -> add account. But, I dont see any way to add territory from my account (account details page), dont see any field added by default.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean assign territories to account. It's the related list in the account page layout. Please see the above picture.

Comment: Yes, I could able to get Territory Related List into my Account details page (After updating Layout). I added territory as you mentioned. Still, I dont see Territories in new Group creation sharing screen.